# Reinitialise directive on change of attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive, angular-directive

I have two directives, calling 2nd directive from 1st directive.

This is my 1st directive

```
    var initializeWidget = function ($compile, $timeout, $rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            maxImages: '@',
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {


            if (!scope.cloudinaryFolder) {
                throw 'folder value is missing in image uploader directive';
            }
            if (!scope.cloudinaryTags) {
                throw 'tags value is missing in image uploader directive';
            }
            //1
            attrs.$observe('maxImages', function (newMaxImages) {
                console.log('varun==' + newMaxImages);
                $timeout(function () {

                    angular.element(document.body).append($compile('<div class="sp-upload-widget" sp-upload-widget up-max-images="' + scope.maxImages + '"></div>')(scope));
                    scope.$apply();
                }, 10);
            });
        }
    };
};
```

I am calling my 2nd directive usixng **angular.element** used in above code.

Below is my 2nd directive:

```
var spUploadWidget = function ($q, Cloudinary, ENV) {
    var templateUrl;
    if ('dev' === ENV.name) {
        templateUrl = '/seller/modules/uploadWidget/views/upload.html';
    }
    else if ('prod' === ENV.name) {
        templateUrl = './views/upload.html';
    }
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {},
        bindToController: {
            maxImages: '=?upMaxImages',
        },
        replace: false,
        controller: 'uploadWidgetController',
        controllerAs: 'up',
        templateUrl: templateUrl,
    };
};
```

now in my controller when I am checking value of maxImages then it is giving the updated value but when I am using this variable to call API then it is holding the older value. Here is my controller

```
console.log('up===' + self.maxImages);
    self.openUploader = function () {
        self.closeModal();
        ABC.UploaderInit( self.maxImages);
    };
```

So when I change the value of maxImages in my directive

```
    <div initialize-widget max-images="maxImages"></div>
```

It should give the updated value to my ABC.UploaderInit function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for my problem,
I was getting this problem because I was calling 2nd directive whenever attribute of 1st directive was changing so I was creating multiple instances of my directive.

So now to handle this I am destroying the older instance of 2nd directive before I call the 2nd directive.

```
                $rootScope.$on('destroySpUploadWidget', function (event, args) {
                if (args.modalId === ctrl.modalId) {
                    scope.$destroy();
                    element.remove();
                }
```